# recovering USB printer

Tags: windows, printer

I have an USB printer, that was discovered and installed properly.
At some point, I suppressed it in the printer view of the config panel.

If I try to add a new local printer, it says :
Only use this option if you don't have an USP printer ( Windows automatically installs USB printer).

How can I make windows automatically reinstall the  USB printer I accidentally suppressed ?

Edit :
It is a dell all-in-one 920 printer, and I just tried to download and reinstall dell software.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is to open device manager (Start > Run > devmgmt.msc) and right click on the Printer under Unknown Devices and select Delete. Then right click on your computer name at the top of the Device Manager list and select "Scan for New Hardware." This will re-detect your device. This works for all devices, not just printers.

Comment: What if that doesn't work/it won't re-detect the printer after doing so?

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided to continue, ignoring the warning about auto install.
I choose local printer, then USB virtual port, then Dell as manufacturer.

I said I had a driver disk and navigated to the previously downloaded drivers. After indicating the inf file, I was informed there was already a driver on my machine, which I decided to keep, and windows proceeded to the step after driver installation, which is adding the printer to the system, so it finally appears in the config panel->printer view

Comment: You could have done it simpler by deleting the printer in Device Manager and rebooting.